# Ruby: How to return single value form ruby each method

Tags: ruby

i have below code which returns hash value at the end of the method . what i want to do is  to return same response without declaring  response = {} in the beginning of the method. how to do this in ruby ?

```
def test 
response = {}
    objects.each do |object|
       response = object.fetch(55)
        break unless response.nil?
    end
   response
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not `return` from the block?

```
def test 
  objects.find do |object|
     response = object.fetch(55)
     return response if response
  end
end
```

Note that this *only* works in a method. You get a LocalJumpError if you try this in irb, for example.

If you just want to get the value out of the block and not actually return from the method, use `break`:

```
def test 
  response = objects.find do |object|
     response = object.fetch(55)
     break response if response
  end
end
```

Comment: @engineersmnky That would return the `object` not the response.

Comment: But, as Cary pointed out, `each` returns `objects` if nothing is found, but find returns `nil`, which is nicer.

Answer (score 3):

You want to return the first result of `fetch(55)`? I'd write it down like this

```
def test
  objects.lazy.map{|o| o.fetch(55)}.reject(&:nil?).first
end
```

Comment: See @SimpleLime's comment on my answer. It seems that you need `o.fetch(55, nil)` or `o[55]`.

Comment: @engineersmnky: "will still have to traverse the entire enum" - not when it's called on a lazy enumerator.

Comment: @engineersmnky: ah, it's a pity you acknowledged your mistake so quickly. I even prepared a script to prove you wrong. What do I do with it now? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Are you now working on a script to disprove my comment?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: you assume it's a hash. Could very well be api client of some sorts. But for hashes - yes, this form of fetch will not work too well.

Comment: `fetch` is not defined in the question. If we assume `objects` is an array of hashes all is well since we know how how `Hash#fetch` works. Else we cannot answer the question; the method may as well be named, `some_mysterious_method`. That was my reason for assuming `objects` is an array of hashes.

Answer (score 2):

If obtaining a value for each element of the given array (presumably a hash) is cheap, you could write the following.

```
def test1(arr)
  arr.find { |h| h[55] }&.[](55)
end
```

else I'd suggest

```
def test2(arr)
  v = nil 
  arr.find { |h| v = h[55] } && v
end
```

even though it doesn't meet your requirement. `&` in the first is the [safe navigation operator](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/), which made its debut in Ruby v2.3. By "cheap" I mean that no extensive calculation is required to determine the value of a key (computing pi to one million digits, for example). See [Hash#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D).

Suppose

```
a1 = [{ 9=>'cat', 14=>'dog', 12=>'pig' }, { 9=>'cat', 55=>'dog', 12=>'pig' }]
a2 = [{ 9=>'cat', 14=>'dog', 12=>'pig' }, { 9=>'cat', 12=>'dog', 12=>'pig' }]
```

then

```
test1(a1)
  #=> 'dog'
test1(a2)
  #=> nil

test2(a1)
  #=> 'dog'
test2(a2)
  #=> nil
```

As pointed out in a comment, the following is a variant of `test1`.

```
def test1(arr)
  arr.find(->{{}}) { |h| h[55] }[55]
end
```

See [Enumerable#find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-find), specifically, if no match is found and `find` has an argument which responds to `call` (namely, a proc or method), that argument is called and the result is returned by `find`. (To use a method rather than a proc: `def m() {} end; arr.find(method(:m)) { |h| h[55] }[55]`.)

Comment: Safe navigation is fun and all but why not just use `arr.find (->{{}}) { |h| h[55] }[55]`?

Comment: @engineersmnky, I just noticed your comment. I believe you are suggesting  `(arr.find ->{{}} { |h| h[55] })[55]`, which works, but I don't understand it. Please explain.

Comment: Sorry  It should have been `arr.find(->{{}}) { |h| h[55] }[55]`. `Enumerable#find` accepts an `ifnone` callable object to be called in the event no matching element is found, so in this case we are just passing a lambda that returns an empty `Hash`. Then we use `Hash#[]` to act on the empty hash or the hash returned by the find block.

Comment: @engineersmnky, I wasn't aware that find takes an optional argument (and has done so since at least v1.9). Good to know. I updated my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby automatically returns the value that is placed in the last line so you can use that logicc

Comment: `objects.each {...}` returns `objects` (`each` always returns its receiver), so removing the line `response` would cause `objects` to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for the first instance in the collection that matches a conditional, ruby has an idiomatic solution: [#detect](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect)

```
object = [{1 => true}, {2 => true}, {55 => 'foo'}, {55 => 'bar'}]
object.detect { |o| o.fetch(55) { false } } #=> {55=>"foo"}
```